# Lagging scroll using foundation on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, scroll, zurb-foundation

I'm using zurb-foundation for a website and I'm facing a really annoying behaviour with the scrolling, when iPhone or iPad is used. For all other mobiles and in desktop it works just fine.

When I disable the foundation script declaration, the scroll behaves in a normal way. We have tried to disable some controls, and even to modify the foundation.js file, but we haven't found the issue.

This is the url of the problem: http://www.semana.com

Thank you